# Trying to find the double dot product of a Rank 4 and Rank 2 tensor

Tags: tensors, dot

I understand this question has been asked before, or something very similar to what I'm trying to accomplish at the very least, however I didn't understand much of what was happening in the other solutions. 
I'm trying to find the double contraction of A, a rank 4 tensor, and B, a rank 2 tensor (a matrix), or A:B, and I'm not sure how to go about doing this on Mathematica. I know that the double contraction (or double dot product) is meant to yield a rank 2 tensor. The equation that I was given and need to solve for does not indicate any indices so I'm not sure how to go about it.

```
    A = KroneckerDelta[9,9]
    B = 0.5*IdentityMatrix[3]
```

I have tried:

```
    Dot[A,B] (*which makes no sense*)
    A*B (*makes absolutely no sense, but I am desperate at this point*)
    Tr[A,Transpose[B]] (*But I think this only works for rank 2 tensors*)
```

Edit: Here is a bit more context.
I'm trying to find the double dot product of the projection tensor P and a matrix which are denoted by the following:

```
    I = Array[KroneckerDelta, {3,3}]; 
    J = Array[KroneckerDelta,{9,9}];
    A = J -((1/3)*TensorProduct[I,I]);
and B = 0.5*IdentityMatrix[3];
```

Yeah. Just need help going about this, any would be great. 
Have a great day

Comment: As said before in [this former post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/209845/38178), `KroneckerProduct` will _never ever_ return a 4-tensor. And `KroneckerProduct[9,9]` is absolutely meaningless---which would have been told to you by _Mathematica_ if you had bothered to test your own code beforehand...

Answer (score 1):

What $A:B$ is supposed to mean is hard to tell without context (I consider it bad notation anyways because I was told in German primary school that "$:$" means division). But my guess is the following:

```
n = 20;
A = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n, n, n}];
B = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}];

a = TensorContract[TensorProduct[A, B], {{3, 5}, {4, 6}}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.63814

More performant variants are however these:

```
b = Activate@TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct][A, B], {{3, 5}, {4, 6}}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First 
c = ArrayReshape[A, {n, n, n^2}].Flatten[B]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.06622
>
> 0.000292

All of them lead to eseentially the same result:

```
Max[Abs[a - b]]
Max[Abs[b - c]]
```

> 8.88178*10^-15
>
> 0.